# Contacts lost in Samsung S3

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

I had my Gmail account linked to Samsung S3, all my contacts were added to this account.  I removed this account and re-added it, and found that all my contacts were lost.

When I checked the Settings it seems the Sync service is not working, and when I checked my contacts' page on Gmail I found only the very old contacts. It means that the Sync service wasn't working since a long time ago.

Is there any possibility to retrieve my contacts from Samsung S3 itself?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this, but there isn't any way to do so as far as I know.

What you can do now, is to simply add your Gmail account to sync at-least your old contacts.

If your sync is not working properly, then do the following:

- Check that Internet connection is working properly on your phone, by resetting your mobile internet connection.
- If above solution isn't working then try restarting your phone after removing your SIM card for at-least 10 minutes.
- If the problem still persists then please contact your service centre for further help.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem.  have you ever linked another Google account (ie Google Voice, G+,...) or anything like Facebook or Hotmail to your Google account?  If so try accessing your contacts via that account. when Google was experiencing sync problems in the past I found ALL of my contacts, new, ancient and forgotten had been automatically synced to my old (and expired) att.net account.  I discovered this when I pulled an old laptop out in order to donate it -luckily on the same day that all my contacts and calender INFO were lost forever!

I was checking the "workings" of the laptop and getting ready to wipe the HD when I accidentally opened the e mail program and saw that the contacts showed to be updated!  first time I beat Murphy's Law.  I contacted Google's Email HELP forum and was told that a "partial sync" had happened and that was the only account that Sync had completed..

Anyway - It would be worth a try, good luck and Back up!